# Reading posted JSON data in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, json, post

I subscribe to a mass email service which, when an error occurs at their end, posts to a page on my website as an endpoint to notify me that an email has bounced.

They describe it as follows:
`The event data is sent in the POST request body using a JSON object.`

What I need to know is how can I capture the info posted to me?
Currently I'm pointing them to a generic handler, a .ashx page, this can be changed to whatever as long as it's in .NET.

In 10 years working with first classic ASP and now .NET I've never done this before and I must admit I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 5):

This is the code I used to achieve a similar thing - not sure where I got it originally.

C#

```
var strJSON = String.Empty;

context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
{
  strJSON = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
}

JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
object serJsonDetails = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(strJSON, typeof(object));

// go and process the serJsonDetails object
```

or VB

```
Dim strJSON = [String].Empty

context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0
Using inputStream = New StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream)
    strJSON = inputStream.ReadToEnd()
End Using

Dim javaScriptSerializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim serJsonDetails As Object = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(strJSON, GetType(Object))

' go and process the serJsonDetails object
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just read the Request stream (`Request.GetRequestStream`) and use Json.NET to deserialize to an object.

You could use MVC4 and the built in object mapping.

There's many options.  Perhaps you should read up on them more so that you have an idea of their capabilities and drawbacks.

Comment: I'm confused as to how to use the Request.GetRequestStream as it seems i need to have a url at which i'm pointing. I don't have a url to point at, my page is the page receiving the post from another server

Comment: I might have gotten the method name wrong.  Doing this off the top of my head.  Use whatever method or property gets you the Request body.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Request.Form [(here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) will help you get the JSON, if you know the content of the post, and then you need something like json.net library to get the object, or you can simply search the string using regex or keywords

Or if you can direct the post to a web service(asmx) instead of a web page, those services will parse the json for you

Comment: i've used web services to retrieve data, but i've never used them to listen for data being sent to it. Any links i can look at on how to do this

Comment: Actually i guess a better question is how do I receive a json object with a webservice written in .net

Comment: I usually define a class that has the same properties  {get; set;} as the JSON object and this class is the parameter of the web service method, and it will make the mappings by itself and transforms the JSOn in you object

Comment: Or you can just accept an object as parameter and then cast it as Dictionary<string,object> and read each property and cast the object as what data type you expect

Comment: I tried to edit this to fix your asMx mistake, but it won't let me cuz it's only one character.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read raw post data twice or many times, i advice you to use this code.

```
    string postBodyJson = null;

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
    Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    Request.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);

    ms.Position = 0;
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms))
    {
        postBodyJson = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```